# excel sorting 2 columns by name

Tags: excel

i have 2 columns like this
[image: first]

i use function `=MATCH(A1;C:C;0)` then sort from smallest to largest
 and result is this
[image: second]

exactly what i want. problem is when i add one value that doesn't exist in one of 2 columns

example (new value marked yellow)

[image: third]

and i got this

[image: fourth]

i would like to group it firstly by repeated columns then rest. how i can do this? :)

Comment: what does it mean by `rest`?

Comment: rest = names that exist only in one column

Comment: (if i get it right.. ) the from the first 2 pictures, is says :  column A = manual input. column B = `MATCH(A1;C:C;0)` formula column C = manual input. right? | In ur case.. (if i get it right.. ) u want to sort both array in such a way that (value that exist in both column at the top & the value that doesn't exist in both column at the bottom.. right?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: it's also important that repeated values has to be next to each other

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-common-values-from-two-lists should settle 1/2 of your problem. | Do it. & later you may [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68401174/edit) this question with how far u [had got](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).. ( :